# Probability from the moment generating function

Tags: probability, statistics, moment-generating-functions

Let $\lambda>0$ be fixed and let $X$ be a random variable with the moment generating function $M_X(t)$ given by

$M_X(t)$=$1$+$\frac{1}{e^\lambda}$($e^t$ $-1$)

How do we find the probability $\mathbb{P}$($X=0$)?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $X$ taking non-negative integer values we have $M_X(t)=\sum P(X=n) e^{nt}$. In this case $M_X(t)=a+be^{t}$ where $a=1-e^{-\lambda}$ and $b=e^{-\lambda}$. Hence, $P(X=0)= a$, $P(X=1)=b$ and $P(X=n)=0$ for all $n \geq 2$. (The fact that $X$ is integer valued follows by uniquness  of the distribution for  agiven MGF).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. How do we know $M_X(t)=a+bt$ and also how do we get the probabilities? Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the uniqeness theorem if you get $M_X(t)=\sum a_ne^{nt}$ then $X$ must be integer valued with $P(X=n)=a_n$. So the idea in this problem is to express $M_X(t)$ in the form $\sum a_ne^{nt}$  which is very easy. @Car